# Get text's tags under this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

JavaScript:

```
var J = jQuery.noConflict();
J('#example tr').click( function() {
  //HERE THE CODE I WANT
} );
```

HTML:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Immat</th>
                <th>Marque</th>
                <th>Modèle</th>
                <th>Contrat</th>
                <th>Début Contrat</th>
                <th>Fin Contrat</th>
                <th>CoûtHT/mois</th>
</tr>


<tr class="odd gradeA">
                <td>2257YY64</td>
                <td>Citroen</td>
                <td>C3</td>
                <td>Star Lease</td>
                <td>27/04/2009</td>
                <td>27/04/2010</td>
                <td>270,02</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd gradeA">
                <td>2257YY64</td>
                <td>Citroen</td>
                <td>C3</td>
                <td>Star Lease</td>
                <td>27/04/2009</td>
                <td>27/04/2010</td>
                <td>270,02</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd gradeA">
                <td>2257YY64</td>
                <td>Citroen</td>
                <td>C3</td>
                <td>Star Lease</td>
                <td>27/04/2009</td>
                <td>27/04/2010</td>
                <td>270,02</td>
            </tr>
```

In a loop i want to get the text ( `text()` method ) of each `td` tag under the `tr` tab that user had clicked.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [.eachh](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to solve your problem.

```
J('#example tr').click( function() {
  J(this).find("td").each(function() {
      alert(J(this).text()); // or whatever else you want to do with the text
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
J('#example tr').click( function() {
  var text="";
  J(this).children("td").each(function(){
     text += J(this).text();
  });
  alert(text);
});
```

Also noticed in your code the `<THEAD>` tag is not closed. This code may not work, if you leave that open.